# Functional test fails with PHPunit on local

Tags: 8, testing

Getting following error when running core functional test with PHPUnit:

> vendor/bin/phpunit -c core/phpunit.xml 
>   core/modules/user/tests/src/Functional/AccessRoleUITest.php

```
There was 1 error:

1) Drupal\Tests\user\Functional\AccessRoleUITest::testAccessRoleUI
Drupal\Core\Installer\Exception\AlreadyInstalledException: <ul>
<li>To start over, you must empty your existing database and copy <em>default.settings.php</em> over <em>settings.php</em>.</li>
<li>To upgrade an existing installation, proceed to the <a href="/update.php">update script</a>.</li>
<li>View your <a href="http://drupal-8-5-demo2.dd:8083">existing site</a>.</li>
</ul>
```

**Phpunit.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- TODO set checkForUnintentionallyCoveredCode="true" once https://www.drupal.org/node/2626832 is resolved. -->
<!-- PHPUnit expects functional tests to be run with either a privileged user
 or your current system user. See core/tests/README.md and
 https://www.drupal.org/node/2116263 for details.
-->
<phpunit bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php" colors="true"
         beStrictAboutTestsThatDoNotTestAnything="true"
         beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true"
         beStrictAboutChangesToGlobalState="true"
         printerClass="\Drupal\Tests\Listeners\HtmlOutputPrinter">
<!-- TODO set printerClass="\Drupal\Tests\Listeners\HtmlOutputPrinter" once
 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-24808 is resolved. Drupal provides a
 result printer that links to the html output results for functional tests.
 Unfortunately, this breaks the output of PHPStorm's PHPUnit runner. However, if
 using the command line you can add
 - -printer="\Drupal\Tests\Listeners\HtmlOutputPrinter" to use it (note there
 should be no spaces between the hyphens).
-->
  <php>
    <!-- Set error reporting to E_ALL. -->
    <ini name="error_reporting" value="32767"/>
    <!-- Do not limit the amount of memory tests take to run. -->
    <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1"/>
    <!-- Example SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL value: http://localhost -->
    <env name="SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL" value="http://drupal-8-5-demo2.dd:8083/"/>
    <!-- Example SIMPLETEST_DB value: mysql://username:password@localhost/databasename#table_prefix -->
    <env name="SIMPLETEST_DB" value="mysql://root:@localhost:8083/drupal_8_5_demo2"/>
    <!-- Example BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY value: /path/to/webroot/sites/simpletest/browser_output -->
    <env name="BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY" value="/Users/gaurav/Sites/devdesktop/drupal-8-5-demo2/sites/default/files/simpletest"/>
    <!-- To disable deprecation testing uncomment the next line. -->
    <env name="SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER" value="weak_vendors"/>
    <!-- Example for changing the driver class for mink tests MINK_DRIVER_CLASS value: 'Drupal\FunctionalJavascriptTests\DrupalSelenium2Driver' -->
    <!-- Example for changing the driver args to mink tests MINK_DRIVER_ARGS value: '["http://127.0.0.1:8510"]' -->
    <!-- Example for changing the driver args to phantomjs tests MINK_DRIVER_ARGS_PHANTOMJS value: '["http://127.0.0.1:8510"]' -->
    <!-- Example for changing the driver args to webdriver tests MINK_DRIVER_ARGS_WEBDRIVER value: '["firefox", null, "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"]' -->
  </php>
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="unit">
      <file>./tests/TestSuites/UnitTestSuite.php</file>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="kernel">
      <file>./tests/TestSuites/KernelTestSuite.php</file>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="functional">
      <file>./tests/TestSuites/FunctionalTestSuite.php</file>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="functional-javascript">
      <file>./tests/TestSuites/FunctionalJavascriptTestSuite.php</file>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
  <listeners>
    <listener class="\Drupal\Tests\Listeners\DrupalListener">
    </listener>
    <!-- The Symfony deprecation listener has to come after the Drupal listener -->
    <listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\SymfonyTestsListener">
    </listener>
  </listeners>
  <!-- Filter for coverage reports. -->
  <filter>
    <whitelist>
      <directory>./includes</directory>
      <directory>./lib</directory>
      <directory>./modules</directory>
      <directory>../modules</directory>
      <directory>../sites</directory>
      <!-- By definition test classes have no tests. -->
      <exclude>
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./</directory>
        <directory suffix="TestBase.php">./</directory>
      </exclude>
     </whitelist>
  </filter>
</phpunit>
```

I have followed [Running PHPUnit tests](https://www.drupal.org/node/2116263) to configure Phpunit.xml, What else I am missing here ?

Comment: can you post what changes you made to get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

I *think* this is because it's not picking up the port number from your mysql host.  I had the same issue and by using a mysql connection on the default port (3306) it started working.

Answer (score 0):

In the phpunit.xml the same port for Base_URL and Database is used, this looks like a mistake.

The `AlreadyInstalledException` is very unhelpful in this case. You have to be really sure the Base_URL is correct and reachable from inside the container, the database connection works and the database is empty, and the BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY is writeable for the user running phpunit. Even with a patch from https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2459671 the exception was suggesting to delete the settings.php, when I really had a stupid typo in the database credentials.